# How do I change the Labels on all three buttons on a UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, title, uinavigationitem

So, I have the below UINavigationBar :

```
[ (<- Back)        Info        (Cancel) ]
```

Now, what I need to do is change the Titles for all the Buttons / Title to `One`, `Two` and `Three`. I tried doing :

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"One";
```

But this only updated the button on the left. How do I change all three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.navigationItem.title` will change the center title, and setting a button with title to `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` will change the right button title.

And here's how I've changed the back button title. Note: this code must be used on the previous view controller (the one you'd be hitting the back button to return to), not the presently viewed controller:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
}
```